How to use css variable in sass function
I wrote the following sass function:
@function multiple-box-shadow($n) {

    $value: '#{random(8000)}px #{random(8000)}px #FFF';

    @for $i from 2 through $n {
        $value: '#{$value} , #{random(8000)}px #{random(8000)}px #FFF';
    }

    @return unquote($value);
}

Instead of the number 8000, I need to substitute the value of the page height, I get it in the following js functions:
const pageHeight = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight,
    document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight);

const topValueNumeric = parseInt(topValue, 10);
const bottomValueNumeric = parseInt(bottomValue, 10);

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--top-value', topValueNumeric);
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--bottom-value', bottomValueNumeric);


When I try to insert a change, I get the error $limit: "var(--bottom-value)" is not a number for `random'
I added the variable in different ways and also rewrote the function in js, but always the same thing. I just started learning sass so I apologize for the trivial question.

SASS gets compiled into CSS, usually on the server side. Are you using a different setup, where this gets compiled dynamically on the client side somehow? If not, then this makes rather little sense to begin with.

That is, if my sass is compiled on the server side in css, then I cannot create a saas variable with a value from css?

Not unless you send that value to the server first, somehow. Plus, you would of course have to re-compile the stylesheet for each individual visitor, because in all likelihood, their devices will have different dimensions, so "page height" is not going to be the same for all of them either.

The fact is that I used this function to animate the stars that go from the bottom of the page to the top, and these values should be the range from the bottom to the top of the page. Maybe you know some other way to specify this range?

I can't tell what you are actually doing with this, from your rudimentary explanation so far - but it would probably make sense to port that whole part to the client-side to begin with. JavAScript has a random number generator as well, and it can set/manipulate CSS variable, or even create stylesheets dynamically on the fly.

Thanks for the idea, I'll try to implement it via js
